# Remove letter which followed by number

Tags: python, regex

If we have the sentence = "George coudn't play football in y. 1998 but plays football at θ. 226",
which by letter I mean any letter from Greek or English vocabulary. Is there any way to have as an output = "George coudn't play football in but plays football in"

I tried this one, which removed only the numbers

```
re_numb = re.compile(r'\d+')
sent = re_numb.sub('', sent)
```

Comment: do you want to remove the rest of the sentence after the match or just remove the character before the number?

Comment: Remember to accept and/or upvote answers that helped you (green tick on the left of an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Unicode range as in

```
\s+[\u03b1-\u03c9]+\.\s+\d+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QDN7kl/1/) and a [**Unicode table for greek letters**](https://unicode-table.com/de/sets/greek-symbols/).

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\s+[\u03b1-\u03c9]+\.\s+\d+')

sentence = "George coudn't play football in γ. 1998 but plays football at θ. 226"
sentence = pattern.sub('', sentence)

print(sentence)
```

And yields

```
George coudn't play football in but plays football at
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, `\w` matches also Greek letters. So you can use:

```
\b\w\. +\d+\b
```

where `\b` is a word boundary.

If you don't want `\w` to match also underscores:

```
\b[^_\W]\. +\d+\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ag6pQ/1)

Comment: thank you so much. Could you please explain me why we need \b?

Comment: The first word boundary forces the letter not to be *preceded* by other letters/numbers, while the second word boundary forces the number not to be *followed* by other letters/numbers. So using them you will *not* match cases like "`0a. 1999`" or "`a. 1999b`". See also [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Just a note that you can force `\w` to only include ascii letters with the `re.ASCII` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex can capture the sentence before `.y 1995` and `θ. 226`

```
(\D)+(?=\s.\.\s\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugAyzE/1)

If you want to capture only up to first match add `^` to only match from the start of the string

```
^(\D)+(?=\s.\.\s\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uv3cqq/1)

**EDIT**
Code sample

To extract each match

```py
import re

text = "George couldn't play football in y. 1998 but plays football at θ. 226"

for match in re.finditer(r'(\D)+(?=\s.\.\s\d+)', text):
    print(match.group(), end='')  # print without new line
```

Output

```
George couldn't play football in but plays football at
```

To extract only the first match

```py
import re

text = "George couldn't play football in y. 1998 but plays football at θ. 226"

for match in re.finditer(r'^(\D)+(?=\s.\.\s\d+)', text):
    print(match.group(), end='')
```

Output

```
George couldn't play football in
```

Comment: thanks a lot. If I do this 
exp = "George coudn't play football in y. 1998 but plays football at θ. 226"
exp = re.sub(r'(\D)+(?=\s.\.\s\d+)', ' ', exp)
exp
for some reason, the output is this
y. 1998  θ. 226. How can I deal with this?

Comment: This regex is to extract what you want, not to substitute what you don't want.  :) use match instead.